# F# 2.0, Silverlight 5, and Excel interop

Tags: com, f#, vsto, silverlight-5.0, excel-interop

Trying to do this:

```
let excel = AutomationFactory.CreateObject "Excel.Application"
excel?Visible <- true
excel?workbooks?Add ()
```

Although EXCEL.EXE does appear in the Task Manager when I run that code, the `excel` object apparently has no properties, which makes the rest of the code pretty tough to execute. (If I place `let allProps = excel.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic)` after the first line, it evaluates to an empty `PropertyInfo` array.)

In examples of Silverlight/Excel interop that I've seen, everyone simply does what I'm trying to do, with no problems.  Not sure why I'm having this issue...??

Comment: Can you tell us the version of: Excel, .NET, and F#?   I also see that you are using the dynamic operator (? with <-) It is used as an operator for dynamic method and property calls. You must provide your own implementation of it, have you done that?

Comment: Excel 2007, .NET 4, and as stated in the title of this question, F# 2.0.

Yes, I've coded the dynamic setter, but again `excel.GetType().GetProperties()` returns an empty array.  My implmentation of `?<-` should have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutomationFactory.CreateObject creates an automation server, which is intended to be used via dynamic dispatch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff457794(v=vs.95).aspx. To me, this makes sense, since the properties available would be defined by the object being automated.

Using object.GetType().GetProperties() will only give you pre-compiled properties of the object, not the dynamic properties.

If you are automating excel to create a spreadsheet, you may have an easier time using a third party library that does not use Excel automation. Many of them are listed in this answer: [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)